# Jquery Submit Form returning target page HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit a form using jQuery.

The problem is that it's returning the target page html instead of the result of submitting the form.

Here is the code:

```
$("#my-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({  
             type: "POST",  
             url: "http://127.0.0.1/upload.html",  
             data: formData,
             async: false,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
             }
        }); 
        return false;
})
```

So the alert(data) is returning the html of the target page. I need it to return the result instead.

How can I fix this?

Console returns: `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: `$(this)[0] === this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The problem is that it's returning the target page html instead of the result of submitting the form.*

**What were you expecting the response would be?** Forms don't have a default result from submitting them.

You are sending the form data to `upload.html`, which is not a server-side resource that can process the form data posted to it and create a custom response, so instead you get the entire contents of the html page as the response since that's what form submissions generally do.

Comment: That's not the problem in this case. upload.html submits to itself and talks to some java applet so it returns a message when posted from the file itself. I'm trying to submit into it from another local file

Comment: Console is returning: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: You have `async: false,` and that's why you are getting that message. Your AJAX request is blocking and that is generally a bad thing.

Comment: I was just hoping to get the message that upload.html gives me when I post directly without javascript

Comment: Your question makes no mention of Java applets (didn't think there were any of those around any more). Your problem must lie there.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL :

url: "http://127.0.0.1/upload.html",

needs to be changed to the place you are trying send your data. Preferably some where connected to a server.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1 is the common IP of a locally running server and is used widely in development.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are trying to do is serialize the form. You can do that using the jQuery serialize function. This should work providing you have the form formatted correctly. The select, input, and labels have to have the correct attributes.

Her is the example from the jQuery documentation.

### HTML............

```
<form>
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>
```

### JAVASCRIPT......................

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

[jQuery form serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: This is not at all what the OP is asking about. You're talking about packaging the data to submit it. The OP is talking about getting a response from the submit target. OP is using `FormData` to package the data. `serialize()` is not needed.